# move innerHTML with append/insertAfter type function, no jQuery

Tags: javascript, append, innerhtml

Similar questions have been asked. I'm looking to clarify the best solution for a specific scenario.

I want to move all the innerHTML to another element. I have:

```
<div class='mydiv'>
    Any HTML could be here. <span></span><div></div> etc..
</div>
```

And want to append/prepend/insertAfter/whatever to this div:

```
<div class='myotherdiv'>
    Any HTML could be here as well. <span></span><div></div> etc..
</div>
```

Is `innerHTML +=` and the like the only viable solution? Or is there some way to move the whole node list from the first div and append it to the second div? I COULD grab every node individually, loop and append them in order to the second div - I **do not** want to do that, for performance reasons. I'm looking for some voodoo magics here, old browser need not apply, and no libraries, please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the most efficient way is to use a `DocumentFragment`:

```
// The following assumes the existence of variables div1 and div2
// pointing to the source and destination divs respectively

var frag = document.createDocumentFragment();
var child;
while ( (child = div1.firstChild) ) {
    frag.appendChild(child);
}

div2.appendChild(frag);
```

If you really wanted to avoid the `while` loop then you could use the [`extractContents()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range.extractContents) method of a DOM Range (note: not supported in IE < 9). Theoretically, it could be more efficient than the previous approach since it reduces the number of DOM calls made by script, but I haven't benchmarked it.

```
var range = document.createRange();
range.selectNodeContents(div1);
var frag = range.extractContents();
div2.appendChild(frag);
```

Comment: +1 nice one. Here is a nice Resig article about document fragment: http://ejohn.org/blog/dom-documentfragments/

Comment: This is pretty awesome! documentFragment removes most of the craziness of appending in a loop. I will play with the extractContents(), didn't even know this existed! Nice work sir!

Answer (score 0):

```
var div = document.getElementsByClassName("mydiv"); // this yeilds an array so your going to have to do some sort of looping with it. Unless you assign your div's a id

//since you don't want to loop assuming you assign them id's
//Also avoids looping through the content nodes of your first div

var div_1 = document.getElementById("first_div"); //div to take stuff from
var div_2 = document.getElementById("second_div"); //div your adding to.

var content = div_1.innerHTML; //or innerText if you just want text

//now you have some options
div_2.innerHTML += content; // just add the old content to new div
div_2.appendChild(div_1) // if you want to just put the whole other div into the new div

//if you know whats in your other div, say like a span or a p tag you can use these
div_2.insertBefore("span or p or whatever", content)
div_2.insertAfter(div_2.firstChild, content) //this would insert after the first element inside your second_div
```